# Use a custom variable as .rolling() window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Can I use another dataframe column as a .rolling() window value?

```
w = df['rolling_window']
df['target'] = df['main_value'].rolling(w).mean()
```

Comment: could you provide a small table as an example? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q8ofDA7T1URH1rRO61ynEjqhd9CSaAbh5wkCLwHfxZ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to take the rolling window column and for each row to calculate the rolling mean on main_value as a separate target column or .. the mean of the rolling mean .. can you provide an example and explanation to your question

Comment: this: *want to take the rolling window column and for each row to calculate the rolling mean on main_value as a separate target column*

Answer (score 0):

OK, meanwhile I have found an answer to this:

`I'm done with Python for data science, I'm moving to Julia!`